# ScrollView is snapping back?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using paging on Scrollview. I have an element which take 1/4th of the screen size. So when the number of elements is greater than 4, scroll sets in. The problem is if the number of elements is in (4n + 1) form i.e 5,9,13... The scrollview snaps back when I take it to last element. It is sort of like this in the gif.

I've tried snapToStart={false} snapToEnd={false}. but it's not working. How to go about this problem

```
renderSpacesCol () {
   var col = []
   this.state.data.map(something => {
      col.push(
        <Col style={styles.containerColSpaces}>
         <Element data={something.someData}/>
        </Col>
      )
   })
   return col
}

render () {
    return ( 
      <View style={styles.containerScrollViewSpaces}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.containerScrollView} horizontal={true} pagingEnabled={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} snapToStart={false}>
          <Grid>
            <Row style={styles.containerRowSpace}>
            {
              this.renderSpacesCol()
            }
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  containerColSpace: {
    flex: 0,
    width: screenWidth/4,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
  },
  containerRowSpace: {
    flex: 0,
    height: 100,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
containerScrollViewSpaces: {
    flex: 0,
    height: 100,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start'
  },
  containerScrollView: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
})
```

[image: gif].

Comment: post appropriate code here

Comment: Please add your code.

Comment: please add your code or share an expo link

Comment: I have added the code. Please take a look!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the [pagingEnabled](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#pagingenabled) prop.

> When true, the scroll view stops on multiples of the scroll view's
>   size when scrolling. This can be used for horizontal pagination.

I've created a demo on snack.expo where you can see ScrollView's behavior with and without `pagingEnabled`.

**DEMO:**

https://snack.expo.io/SyVC2aNAS

Comment: My thing works fine when paging is disabled. Is there a way to solve this when paging is enabled?

Comment: @VedantBajaj in your example you don't need paging enabled, so just leave it turned off